# Why does setting the pixel color using `color` give such bad performance

Tags: javascript, colors, processing

I am writing a physics simulation and want to postprocess the results using P5*JS (a JS implementation of the Processing language).

I am using the following piece of code to set the color of each pixel:

```
colorMode(RGB,1);
for (var x = 0; x < nX; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < nY; y++) {
    var id = getIdx(x,y);
    var v = vArray[id]; //range=[0,1]
    var c = color(v, 0, 1-v);
    set(x, y, c);
  }
}
updatePixels();
```

It is very straightforward; i get a value from an array `vArray` which is in the range `[0,1]`. A color `c` is is calculated using `color()` and pixel `[x,y]` is set to `c`.

Unfortunately, this has very bad performance compared to the rest of my code; `color()` takes approximately `60%` of the CPU time:

[image]

It is a huge bottleneck compared to the rest of the code which should be the bottleneck considering it is doing heavy work. If i move `color()` out of the loop the code runs efficiently again (ofcours without coloring the pixels):

[image]

Does anyone know why `color()` is so inefficient? How can I avoid this inefficiency, either by modifying the use of `color()` or perhaps by setting the pixel color in some other way?

**Edit**: As it turns out `color()` contains many `if` checks. I found much better performance could be achieved by passing an array containing color data to `set()` directly:

```
for (var x = 0; x < nX; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < nY; y++) {
    var id = getIdx(x,y);
    var v = vArray[id]; //range=[0,1]
    var c = [255*v, 0, 255*(1-v), 255];
    set(x, y, c);
  }
}
updatePixels();
```

`colorMode()` does not need to be explicitly set anymore.

Comment: Doing per-pixel operations on the CPU is notoriously bad for performance since they have to be done one at a time. Hardware graphics cards have GPUs which can process hundreds or thousands of per-pixel operations all at once. Is there an API with "P5*JS" to supply a filter function which can be used more efficiently? If not, the best could could do would be to pre-process the colours that need to be used to make the inner loop as efficient as possible.

Comment: Did you try [colorMode()](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/colorMode)?

Comment: The problem is not that `color()` is inefficient, or even that it's taking a long time. The problem is that you're calling it for every single pixel in your image. What exactly are you trying to do to the image?

Comment: @Douglas - i agree, but i am not aware of such a filter. Making the inner loop as efficient as possible is the reason why i am asking here.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni - what do you mean 'did i try'? it is the first line of my code.

Comment: Did you try to use different color systems or color ranges?

Comment: @KevinWorkman - The array `vArray` contains velocity magnitude data and i am mapping each value to a color and `setting` the pixel to that color and after the loop i call `updatePixels()` which i assume updates all pixels in batch. I will need to process each pixel (element of vArray) to do what i want, or not?.

Comment: @nluigi Are you actually experiencing a performance problem, or are you just "worried" that the `color()` function is taking up more time than you expect?

Comment: @KevinWorkman - `domain.collide` is a heavy function and is also calculated for each pixel. I 'expect' color() to not do much more than map a value between `[0,1]` to an rgb color `[0,255]` and `set` the pixel to that color. `color()` in my opinion should not take 4 times as long as `domain.collide`. Comparing the profiles in my question, i am definitely experiencing a performance problem.

Comment: @nluigi Without seeing `domain.collide()`, I can't comment on that. Consider posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But really, are you actually experiencing a performance problem, or are you just wondering why the `color()` function is taking up more CPU than you expected?

Comment: @KevinWorkman - I have added simulation and source to the question, if you are interested. Both; i expect `color()` to not be the bottleneck, but since it is i would also like to know why. I call this a performance problem; total CPU usage contains 60% visualization, to 30% simulation... it should atleast be the other way around

Comment: @nluigi Your visualization code is more involved than your simulation code. It's going to take more CPU. If you don't have an actual performance problem, this is a non-issue. If you do have a performance problem, then you have to think about alternative approaches: the problem is that you're doing per-pixel calculations, not that you're using the `color()` function.

Comment: Crossposted: http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/13114/why-does-using-color-have-such-bad-performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand what the `color()` function is doing, the best thing you can do is go to [the source](http://processingjs.org/download/).

Here is the start of the `color()` function:

```
p.color = function(aValue1, aValue2, aValue3, aValue4) {

      // 4 arguments: (R, G, B, A) or (H, S, B, A)
      if (aValue1 !== undef && aValue2 !== undef && aValue3 !== undef && aValue4 !== undef) {
        return color$4(aValue1, aValue2, aValue3, aValue4);
      }

      // 3 arguments: (R, G, B) or (H, S, B)
      if (aValue1 !== undef && aValue2 !== undef && aValue3 !== undef) {
        return color$4(aValue1, aValue2, aValue3, colorModeA);
      }

      // 2 arguments: (Color, A) or (Grayscale, A)
      if (aValue1 !== undef && aValue2 !== undef) {
        return color$2(aValue1, aValue2);
      }

      // 1 argument: (Grayscale) or (Color)
      if (typeof aValue1 === "number") {
        return color$1(aValue1);
      }

      // Default
      return color$4(colorModeX, colorModeY, colorModeZ, colorModeA);
    };
```

That then calls the `color$4()` function:

```
 function color$4(aValue1, aValue2, aValue3, aValue4) {
      var r, g, b, a;

      if (curColorMode === PConstants.HSB) {
        var rgb = p.color.toRGB(aValue1, aValue2, aValue3);
        r = rgb[0];
        g = rgb[1];
        b = rgb[2];
      } else {
        r = Math.round(255 * (aValue1 / colorModeX));
        g = Math.round(255 * (aValue2 / colorModeY));
        b = Math.round(255 * (aValue3 / colorModeZ));
      }

      a = Math.round(255 * (aValue4 / colorModeA));

      // Limit values less than 0 and greater than 255
      r = (r < 0) ? 0 : r;
      g = (g < 0) ? 0 : g;
      b = (b < 0) ? 0 : b;
      a = (a < 0) ? 0 : a;
      r = (r > 255) ? 255 : r;
      g = (g > 255) ? 255 : g;
      b = (b > 255) ? 255 : b;
      a = (a > 255) ? 255 : a;

      // Create color int
      return (a << 24) & PConstants.ALPHA_MASK | (r << 16) & PConstants.RED_MASK | (g << 8) & PConstants.GREEN_MASK | b & PConstants.BLUE_MASK;
    }
```

This function has if statements, rounding, then bit shifting. This is "more work" than your `collide()` function. At its core, that's why this is "taking more time".

But that's not saying that the `color()` function is a "bottleneck" or "inefficient". You're calling the `color()` function for every single pixel in your image, which is pretty much guaranteed to take up more CPU than anything else.

You might try to think about alternative approaches: do you really need to do this for every single pixel? Do you really need to do this every single frame?

But really, if you aren't noticing any problems with your framerate, then this is a non-issue. It seems to bother you that the `color()` function is taking more CPU time, but I would argue that you're focusing on the wrong thing. Premature optimization is the root of all evil, and all that.

Comment: ok, i see that `color()` is indeed doing more work then i thought. Obviously that is not the way to go. My point is that i am having framerate issues; it is not that i am running at 29fps with `color()` and 30fps with. I am running 10fps with color() and 30fps without `color()`, regardless of `collide()`. Since you say i am focusing on the wrong thing (premature optimization) what do you suggest should be optimized instead.

Comment: @nluigi Well, I made that statement before you said you were actually noticing a problem with your framerate. You could try to create your own `color()` function that removes the rounding and any other extra work, but I doubt that will give you a huge speed boost.

Comment: I get much better performance setting the color directly using an array. see my edit to my question.